# Microsoft Paint-Like Features on Android with SurfaceView and Canvas

Tags: android, drawing, android-canvas, surfaceview

I'm trying to create a simpel floorplan drawing tool for an app using SurfaceView and Canvas. However, I can't figure out how to realise a screen with different buttons for different shapes and a surfaceView + Canvas where the user can draw the selected shapes.

I need something much like Microsoft Paint, but then even less demanding. Is this even possible with SurfaceView and Canvas, or is OpenGL a better solution?

Comment: You want this kind of thing ? http://trivedihardik.wordpress.com/2013/01/24/android-canvas-painting-demo/  I guess its good to at least start with

Comment: Exactly! I must have searched with the wrong keywords. Thanks!